# What is the correct cameraViewTransform to apply to UIImagePickerController?

Tags: ios, uiimagepickercontroller, camera-overlay

I'm trying to put a custom overlay over a `UIImageCameraPickerController`. To avoid the white space at the bottom I know I have to apply a scale transform of `1.24299` in the Y axis.

Why that value? Is that value correct in iPhone 5? Can I calculate that value taking into account screen height instead of hardcoding it?

Thank you.